# Convert JSONArray to String[]

Tags: android, string, arrays

Having some problems trying to format a JSONArray, it has to come out like this:

```
String[] titles = {"commentator name 1", "commentator name 2", "commentator name 3"};
```

This is my JSON:

```
"commentator": [
    "commentator name 1",
    "commentator name 2",
    "commentator name 3"
]
```

and this is my Code:

```
// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = userFunction.getAudios();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    commentator = json.getJSONArray(TAG_COMENTATOR);
    Log.d("COMMENTATOR", commentator.toString());
    //System.out.println("*****COMMENTATOR*****" + commentator.length());

    if(commentator != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < commentator.length(); i++) {
            Log.d("FOR LOOP", "Value: " + commentator.getString(i));
            list.add( commentator.getString(i) );
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String[] titles = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

But im getting an index out of bounds error with this code, im guessing its not well formatted, any ideas?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 JSONArray jsonArr=new JSONArray(resultString);
 JSONArray jsonArr2=jsonArr.getJSONArray(0);
 for(int i = 0; i < jsonArr2.length(); i++)
 {
      list.add(jsonArr2.getString(i).);
 }
```

`resultString` is the json string..
It iterate to all the json array and add it to your ArrayList of String

Comment: im getting same error **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** with your code, also error **cannot be converted to JSONArray** in `JSONArray jsonArr2 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);`, i did a print of the JSONArray and is formatted like this `["Comentarista 2","Informe Jornadas","Tablas Informativas"]`, any change to change it to String[] {"1", "2", "3"} from there?

Comment: @RonEskinder did you chagne the variablename cause I mix it up try the updated code above

Answer (score 0):

Jour json is invalid, evrything in Json has to be either a object or an array you can't just start with a key.

try this

```
{
    "commentator": 
    [
        "commentator name 1",
        "commentator name 2",
        "commentator name 3"
    ]
}
```

You can always check you json here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/